# Control FTP access from SQL table

Tags: sql-server, ftp

I'm trying to set up my first FTP site. I would like to be able to take advantage of IIS6 isolation mode, but I can not figure out how to control the user accounts without manually adding each one (there are currently just over 1100 accounts).

All of my usernames and passwords are already stored in a SQL table that is used by a website to control access. I would like to be able to use the same usernames and passwords for the FTP site.

Is there any way to have IIS use the SQL table or, if not, a way to create local user accounts and keep the passwords synced?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no way for IIS 6's FTP service to use any authentication system other than Windows users (be them domain or local ones).

You could use some scripting (I'd strongly suggest PowerShell, it's easy to query SQL Server from there) to automatically create those user accounts... but I'm afraid keeping them synced would not be such an easy task.

There are other FTP servers around, of course; probably some of them can use a SQL database for authentication; a bit of googling turned out this one, for example (although not free): http://www.g6ftpserver.com.

Comment: I ended up using CrushFTP and have a sql job that keeps the passwords in sync.

Answer (score 0):

With IIS 7 it's [relatively easy](http://learn.iis.net/page.aspx/389/configuring-ftp-with-net-membership-authentication/) if you're using the .NET Membership Provider.  I'm afraid that you'll probably have to roll your own for IIS 6 but I'm still investigating it for you.